# Do single/double quotes make a difference if nothing is escaped?

Tags: javascript, string, google-chrome, quotes, bookmarklet

As I see it, both `'mars%22%3A%22'` and `"mars%22%3A%22"` are equivalent, as nothing is being escaped.

I have been creating a javscript bookmarklet for some time now. At one point, it stopped working when pasted as-is into a bookmark in Chrome.

I discovered a solution after much guess-and-check:
**A pair of double quotes needed to be single quotes. Why?**

The following line with single-quotes inside split() causes no problems in a bookmarklet:

```
loadDoc("/page1/" + aArray[i].href.split('mars%22%3A%22')[1].slice(0,7),i);
```

The line below with all double quotes will cause a bookmarklet not to run at all:

```
loadDoc("/page1/" + aArray[i].href.split("mars%22%3A%22")[1].slice(0,7),i);
```

No error is shown in the console.

Note that the double-quote version will run just fine if pasted into the javascript console directly!

What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript does not distinguish between single and double quotes in the way that a language like Ruby does (where string interpolation and backslash escape sequences only work in a double-quoted string). Both types of quote have the same meaning in JavaScript.

The one difference is that whichever type of quote you use, that same quote can't be used inside the string unless you escape it with a backslash or URL-encode it.

In the case of your bookmarklet, the browser unescapes the entire `javascript:...` URL string before executing it. You can test this with a simple case like `javascript:alert('foo%22bar')` which will alert the text `foo"bar`.

So your string `mars%22%3A%22` is converted to `mars":"` before the code runs. Since this string has double-quotes in it, it can only be used inside a single-quoted string.

BTW, is my hunch correct that you may be attempting to parse or manipulate a JSON text here? If you are, it would be better to use `JSON.parse()` instead of the raw string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

mars%22%3A%22 is an encoded string. So when it decoded before compilation it would be like mars":". So the line below

```
loadDoc("/page1/" + aArray[i].href.split("mars%22%3A%22")[1].slice(0,7),i);
```

splits href based on "mars":"", And the line below

```
loadDoc("/page1/" + aArray[i].href.split('mars%22%3A%22')[1].slice(0,7),i);
```

splits href based on 'mars":"' which makes the difference.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript `'...'` and `"..."` are **exactly the same** provided that the content doesn't include single or double quotes.

If there is a difference then that is a bug in the code manipulating your Javascript code because apparently it handles correctly only escaping of double quotes. It's not a problem in the code itself...